# What is the maximum allowed run time memory size of an iPad app?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipa

I am developing an iPad app ( hybrid), which has native UINavigationbar and UIWebview ,thats all. I load webview with external url. It works fine for some time . But after that it is getting crashed with log in console "Received memory warning." twice. I checked the "Instruments" , it has very very less leaks discovered (around 100 bytes) and objective-codes are not all executed at that time

It clearly shows that app size increased the threshold.But is there any way to increase the size of the app , so that it will not throw memory warning error. How to handle this issue?

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have to respond to memory warnings changed in iOS 5/6. Before that you would get like three memory warnings and would be killed if you didn't do anything. Now the OS sends memory warnings more as a last resort - if you receive one, you really have to drop your footprint now. This is only indirectly linked with memory leaks.

As the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MemoryAlloc.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001881-CJBCFDGA) detail, you have to respond to those notifications - and it is good to not allocate a lot of memory in a short time.

Since iOS 7 keeps even more of the suspended apps around (e.g. for the new background modes) you might get memory warnings more often.

It's important to note, that you cannot control the amount of memory your app will be reserved by the system.